# Old SSD: get application license number using SATA adapter cable

Tags: windows, sata, sata-to-usb

My old laptop was having issues with power connector (which eventually just stopped altogether), so I recently bought a new desktop. I have copied data from old Laptop to new desktop using a SATA adapter cable but how do I find out the license number of Microsoft office (version 2007) on old laptop? I don't want to pay for license again.

Any help is much appreciated.

Details of Office application:

- Product name: 2007 Microsoft Office system
- Product version: 12.0.6787.5000

Comment: How have you copied the data? Have you cloned it? What version of Office?

Comment: Thanks for your message. To copy files: I plugged one end of the SATA Adapter to old SSD and the USB end to new desktop and then just copied and pasted the files. This was office 2007.

Comment: (1) Which Office version is it ? (2) Did you use a Microsoft Account on the old laptop? (3) Did you get it from the Microsoft Store? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Thanks for your message. I updated question with Office version details. It is quite an old laptop (almost 10 years old), it came with MS office preinstalled. @harrymc

Comment: Try on the old laptop in CMD the command `cscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OSPP.vbs" /dstatus` (the "Office12" part is a guess). You could also try [ProduKey](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html).

Comment: That won’t work since that script only looks at the registry hive on the system disk.